# Qt dynamically loading layouts with custom widgets

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I need to implement a list of layouts with custom widgets inside of them.This list of layouts is inside QTabWidget tab. By pressing a button inside this tab i should add and remove these layouts. I use QMap for accessing this list. My problem is with rendering those widgets on UI.  They are not displayed or removed. Also I have

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to TabWidget "", which already has a layout

Which I understand how to eliminate. But I cannot add new layout by click.

**mainshowtabwidget.cpp**

```
void MainShowTabWidget::showNewLayoutTest() 
{
    ShowRequisitePropsWidget * propsWidget = new ShowRequisitePropsWidget;
    TimelineWidget * timelineWidget = new TimelineWidget;
    Waveform * waveform = new Waveform(this); //these 3 are my custom widgets        
    QHBoxLayout * actorLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this); //for a single item
    actorLayout - > addWidget(waveform);
    setLayout(actorLayout);
    QHBoxLayout * hl = new QHBoxLayout();
    hl - > addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(10, 1, QSizePolicy::Expanding,
        QSizePolicy::Fixed));
    windowLayout - > addItem(actorLayout);
    windowLayout - > addLayout(actorLayout); //horizontal layout
    actorsMap.insert(showObjectsCounter, actorLayout);
    showObjectsCounter++;
    //  setLayout(windowLayout);
    //    repaint();

}
```

I want to display a new horizontal layout with these three widgets on my tab after button click

Comment: QTabWidget already has a layout by default, this layout is used to place the pages so you should not and can not change the layout, what you should do is create a widget and in it to host the layouts.

Comment: can default tab widget host layouts inside?

Comment: A QTabWidget is actually a QTabBar that controls a QStackWidget, and this QStackWidget saves only widgets, since internally it has a layout, and this makes the corresponding widget visible, that gives the effect of pages. So I recommend you do your logic in a widget, and then add or insert a page of the QTabWidget.